# Error in Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java

I'm facing this problem:

> Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

But i can't detect what am i wrong...

Follow bellow my code:

Constants.java

```
public static final String INSERTDEVICES = "insert into devices (I_ENVIRONMENT,"
                                                + "I_APP_ID,E_STATUS,DT_MODIFIED,"
                                                + "DT_LAST_COMMUNICATION,"
                                                + "DT_CREATED,DS_ENDPOINT_ARN,"
                                                + "DS_DEVICE_VERSION,DS_DEVICE_UID,"
                                                + "DS_DEVICE_TOKEN,DS_DEVICE_NAME,"
                                                + "DS_DEVICE_MODEL,DS_APP_VERSION,"
                                                + "B_PUSHSOUND,B_PUSHBADGE,B_PUSHALERT, I_ID_SYSTEM) "
                                                + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

DeviceDAO.java

```
DBConnect db = DBConnect.getInstance();

        try {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            String dName = device.getDeviceName().replace("%20", " ");
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(Constants.INSERTDEVICES);

            preparedStatement.setLong(1, device.getEnvironment().ordinal());
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, device.getAppID().ordinal());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "active");
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(6, new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setString(7, device.getEndPointArn());
            preparedStatement.setString(8, device.getDeviceVersion());
            preparedStatement.setString(9, device.getDeviceUID());
            preparedStatement.setString(10, device.getDeviceToken());
            preparedStatement.setString(11, dName);
            preparedStatement.setString(12, device.getDeviceModel());
            preparedStatement.setString(13, device.getAppVersion());
            preparedStatement.setBoolean(14, device.isPushSound());
            preparedStatement.setBoolean(15, device.isPushBadge());
            preparedStatement.setBoolean(16, device.isPushAlert());
            preparedStatement.setLong(17, device.getSystem().ordinal());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The exception is raised in this line:

```
preparedStatement.setLong(2, device.getAppID().ordinal());
```

Enums:
getApID() = Enum EApplication (Type of the application we want use)
device.getEnvironment() = Enum EEnvironment (Homologation, Production)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try printing out `Constants.INSERTDEVICES`. it may not be the value you've shown here....

Comment: What is `device.getAppID()` and `device.getAppID().ordinal()` ??

Comment: Added information at the body of the question...

Comment: why you are using setLong for ordinal values if they retrieve int values?